# Executable file generated from cx_Freeze not running on other computers

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, exe, cx-freeze

I have used the following 'setup.py' file in order to convert my python file into an executable file. The executable file generated within the 'build' directory executes perfectly on my laptop but does not run at all on my brother's laptop (I used cx_Freeze to do this).
My laptop is the exact same make as my brothers. Only differences are: I have Python 3.4.4 installed (as well as Pygame) and he does not, and I have Windows 8 and he has Windows 10. I cannot find the problem. Is it due to 'cx_Freeze'? Is it cause I have Python and he does not? Surely the executable file should run on any windows computer... Below is my 'setup.py' file.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Pythongame",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Game made with Pygame",
    executables = [Executable("Pythongame.py", base="Win32GUI")],
    )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

NOTE: I require base="Win32GUI"as pygame creates a GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you need to copy all the directory Like build because he contains librarys (dll and other) 

Or this exe is generated just for your windows like (win7 64bit)

i suggest you to use Pyinstaller

Comment: I have copied the entire directory, I know this. Could be that "this exe is generated just for your windows like (win7 64bit)"...hmmm

Comment: I am going to try py2exe

Comment: How to write the 'setup' file? Could you link me a tutorial for it?

Comment: Got it to work, tysm for the help! Basically I used py2exe instead of cx_Freeze. Thanks!